# re-writing large XML Files - excluding certain node

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I would like to re-write a large xml without some of its nodes.
I'm trying to read an XML file (100s of MBs, can't read it all to memory) line by line using system.xml.xmlreader - struggling to find a way to read parts of it, write them down to a separate xDocument and then save that xDocument to the disk.

What i've been thinking is something like:

```
      using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(_xml_path))
        {
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"filteredxml.xml"))
            {
                reader.MoveToContent();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                    {
                        if (reader.Name != "EL_TO_BE_REMOVED")
                        {
                           //writer.WriteNode(reader.ReadOuterXml());

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

but reader.ReadOuterXml() simply goes to the first element and writes all its descendants to a file, without letting me filter for elements I wish to ignore.

Comment: See my answer at following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34274568/how-to-read-an-xml-file-by-using-xmlreader-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of a big file and memory constraints, you should parse with SAX instead of DOM: the XMLReader is the C# equivalent indeed.

This could be a basic approach with a XMLReader for the input, a XMLWriter for the output and a counter to remove nodes named RemoveMe (with all their content).

Notice the internal loop to clone the attributes per each relevant element.

```
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(OriginalXml))
        {
            XmlWriterSettings ws = new XmlWriterSettings();
            ws.Indent = true;
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FilteredXml, ws))
            {
                int skip = 0;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    switch (reader.NodeType)
                    {
                        case XmlNodeType.Element:
                            skip += reader.Name.Equals(RemoveMe) ? 1 : 0;
                            if (skip == 0)
                            {
                                writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
                                while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
                                    writer.WriteAttributeString(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                            }

                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.Text:
                            if (skip == 0)
                            {
                                writer.WriteString(reader.Value);
                            }
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                        case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                            if (skip == 0)
                            {
                                writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                            }   
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                            if (skip == 0)
                            {
                                writer.WriteComment(reader.Value);
                            }
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                            if (skip == 0)
                            {
                                writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                            }
                            skip -= reader.Name.Equals(RemoveMe) ? 1 : 0;
                            if (skip < 0)
                            {
                                throw new Exception("wrong sequence");
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Answer updated now, thanks again to @JLRishe for the precious suggestions

Comment: your code works perfectly. and is exactly what i needed and i thank you for that. question though about the sequence, is it possible the sequence will NOT be ordered correctly ? other than corrupt XML ?

Comment: I also think so: only a corrupted xml. Thanks again for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for [XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info).

XSL Transform (RemoveElement.xslt):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="EL_TO_BE_REMOVED" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

C# code to execute the transform:

```
var transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
transform.Load("xslt/path/RemoveElement.xslt");

transform.Transform("input/xml/path/inputFile.xml", "output/xml/path/outputFile.xml");
```

Comment: @MachineLearning I think that's just a general outline of how XSLTs are often executed and isn't based on anything in the XSLT spec (AFAIK). I don't know how .NET's XSLT processor is implemented, but since it is designed to operate on input and output streams, it might do so in a fairly smart way. Worth a try, at least.